# How can I disable the return_bind_key in PySimpleGui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I need to disable the bind_return_key parameter to false after a question is answered incorrectly. The parameter is binded to the submit button under the key 'b1'. I used the .update() method and it worked around a week ago. It not longer works and I receive this error: "TypeError: update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind_return_key'"

Is there a fix to this?

Things I've tried:

- changed what is being updated from key 'b1' to 'Submit'
- opened a new project file to install the newest version which I think is 4.55.1

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import json

data = {
    "question": [
        "Q1. What is the equation for force",
        "Q2. Define isotope",
        "Q3. Define wavelength",
        "Q4. Define modal dispersion"
    ],
    "answers": [

        "f=ma",
        "isotopes are atoms of the same element but with a different number of neutrons",
        "the least distance between adjacent particles which are in phase",
        "causes light travelling at different angles to arrive at different times"

    ],
    "automark": [
        ["force=massxacceleration"],
        ["same number of protons", "different number of neutrons", "same element"],
        ["minimum distance between adjacent particles", "particles which are in phase"],
        ["different angles", "different times"]
    ],
    "markscheme": [
        ["force=massxacceleration"],
        ["same number of protons", "different number of neutrons", "same element"],
        ["minimum distance between adjacent particles", "particles which are in phase"],
        ["different angles", "different times"]
    ],
    "mastery": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ],
    "incorrect": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ]
}


def nextset(no, no2, do_not_stop, list1, list2):
    endlist = []  # number in the list represent question number
    while not do_not_stop:
        if no == 3:
            do_not_stop = True

        if list2[no] == list1[no2]:
            position = list1.index(list2[no])
            no += 1
            no2 = 0
            endlist.append(position)
            print(endlist)

        else:
            no2 += 1
    savetoexternal(endlist)


def savetoexternal(endlist):
    with open("savefile.json", 'w') as f:  # creates external json file to be read from later
        json.dump(endlist, f, indent=2)


# main program
def listdata(list1):
    do_not_stop = False
    no = 0
    no2 = 0
    list2 = list1.copy()
    list2.sort(
        reverse=True)  # ordered question from highest to lowest while keeping original intact to preserve question number
    print(list1)
    print(list2)
    nextset(no, no2, do_not_stop, list1, list2)


def main():
    # initialise the question, question number and answer
    question = data['question']
    answers = data['answers']
    automark = data['automark']
    markscheme = data['markscheme']
    mastery = data['mastery']
    incorrect = data['incorrect']
    q_no = 0
    max_q_no = 4

    sg.theme('DarkBlack')  # Adding colour
    # Stuff in side the window

    layout = [[sg.Text("                      "), sg.Text(question[0], key='_Q1_', visible=True),
               sg.Text(size=(60, 1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
              [sg.Text("correct answer:"), sg.Text(size=(60, 1), key='-OUTPUTA-')],
              [sg.Text("automark allows:"), sg.Text(size=(60, 1), key='-OUTPUTB-')],
              [sg.Text("your answer was:"), sg.Text(size=(60, 1), key='-OUTPUTC-')],
              [sg.Text('Answer here:   '), sg.InputText(size=(60, 1), key='-INPUT-', do_not_clear=False)],
              [sg.Button('Submit', key='b1', bind_return_key=True), sg.Button('Cancel'), sg.Button('Skip')]]

    # Create the Window
    window = sg.Window('Rerevise', layout, size=(655, 565))
    # Event Loop to process "events" and get the "values" of the inputs
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':  # if user closes window or clicks cancel
            break

        window['_Q1_'].Update(visible=False)
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update(question[q_no])
        select_not_mastered_question = True
        already_correct = False

        if all(x == 3 for x in mastery):
            print("all questions mastered")  # add to gui later
            list1 = []
            q_no = 0
            while q_no < max_q_no:
                list1.append(incorrect[q_no])
                q_no += 1
            q_no = 0
            listdata(list1)

        if values['-INPUT-'].lower() == answers[q_no]:  # list index out of range occurs when all questions are complete, need to add completed screen by using else statement
            mastery[q_no] += 1  # need to add to gui
            print(mastery)
            q_no += 1
            if q_no == max_q_no:
                q_no = 0

            while select_not_mastered_question:  # make sures the next question has not already been mastered
                if mastery[q_no] == 3:
                    if q_no == max_q_no:
                        q_no = 0
                    q_no += 1
                else:
                    select_not_mastered_question = False

            window['-OUTPUT-'].update(question[q_no])  # accepts the answer as correct and moves onto the next question
            window['-OUTPUTA-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUTB-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUTC-'].update('')

        if all(answer in values['-INPUT-'].lower() for answer in automark[q_no]):
            print(automark[q_no])
            mastery[q_no] += 1  # need to add to gui
            print(mastery)
            q_no += 1
            if q_no == max_q_no:
                q_no = 0

            while select_not_mastered_question:  # make sures the next question has not already been mastered
                if mastery[q_no] == 3:
                    if q_no == max_q_no:
                        q_no = 0
                    q_no += 1
                else:
                    select_not_mastered_question = False

            window['-OUTPUT-'].update(question[q_no])  # accepts the answer as correct and moves onto the next question
            window['-OUTPUTA-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUTB-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUTC-'].update('')

            already_correct = True

        if any(answer in values['-INPUT-'].lower() for answer in automark[q_no]):  # shows the answer was correct but missing some key points
            if already_correct:
                return
            else:
                window['-OUTPUTA-'].update(answers[q_no])
                window['-OUTPUTB-'].update(markscheme[q_no])
                window['-OUTPUTC-'].update('partially correct')
                window['-INPUT-'].update(disabled=True)
                window['b1'].update(disabled=True)
                window['b1'].update(bind_return_key=False)

        if event == 'Skip':
            q_no += 1
            if q_no == max_q_no:
                q_no = 0

            while select_not_mastered_question:  # make sures the next question has not already been mastered
                if mastery[q_no] == 3:
                    if q_no == max_q_no:
                        q_no = 0
                    q_no += 1
                else:
                    select_not_mastered_question = False

            window['-OUTPUT-'].update(question[q_no])  # moves onto the next question
            window['-OUTPUTA-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUTB-'].update('')
            window['-OUTPUTC-'].update('')
            window['-INPUT-'].update(disabled=False)
            window['b1'].update(disabled=False)
            window['b1'].update(bind_return_key=True)

        elif values['-INPUT-'] == '':
            print('answer was:', answers[q_no])  # for testing
            window['-OUTPUTA-'].update(
                answers[q_no])  # shows that the answer is incorrect and displays the right answer
            window['-OUTPUTB-'].update(markscheme[q_no])
            window['-OUTPUTC-'].update('incorrect')
            window['-INPUT-'].update(disabled=True)
            window['b1'].update(disabled=True)
            window['b1'].update(bind_return_key=False)
            incorrect[q_no] += 1
            if mastery[q_no] == 0:
                print(mastery)
            else:
                mastery[q_no] -= 1
                print(mastery)

    window.close()


main()
```

Comment: bind_return_key has not been a valid parm to update in the past. The bind is on the input element, not the button. If no button has bind set, then it'll be ignored.  I you wish to request an enhancement so that it can be changed via update, open an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To both enable and disable the bind to return key feature, you can simply change a member variable in your buttons.

The "Bind" at the tkinter level is not on the button, so unbinding from the button won't have an impact.

In my *opinion*, the simplest approach is to check what to do if the button is detected.. you can take action, or ignore it.  Rather than relying on the button's setting, rely on a setting in your code that you're in a "state" where it should be ignored.  The user will be able to CLICK your button too I assume.

The error your getting is simply because you're calling update with the wrong parms.  See the call ref for the valid list, or look at the docstring.

If you **really** want to enabled/disable the binding of the return key, then you can use the member variable `Button.BindReturnKey`.  The first button that has this flag set to True will be what's returned to you when Return is pressed.

Here's example code for doing variable manipulations.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [  [sg.Text('My Window')],
            [sg.Input(key='-IN-')],
            [sg.Text(size=(20,1), key='-OUT-')],
            [sg.Button('Go1', bind_return_key=True), sg.B('Go2'), sg.B('Switch to Go2'), sg.B('Disable')]  ]

window = sg.Window('Bind Return Key', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    window['-OUT-'].update(f'{event, values}')
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Switch to Go2':
        window['Go1'].BindReturnKey = False
        window['Go2'].BindReturnKey = True
    elif event == 'Disable':
        window['Go1'].BindReturnKey = window['Go2'].BindReturnKey = False
window.close()
```

This is how it looks....

[image]

Comment: Note the significant difference in addressing the window-element, i.e. by the button-text `Go1` instead using an extra key like `b1`. Applied to original code with following improvements: (a) makes the button-definition simpler; (b) expresses the intend clearer (dis-/enable button-to-returnKey-binding): `window['Submit'].BindReturnKey = True`

Comment: There are a number of reasons I don't suggest putting keys on buttons, unless absolutely necessary. They add unnecessary complexity. But thanks for thinking about the code. Maybe when you use the package you'll pick up on a few of these. They're discussed in the lessons for example. Glad you're learning more and trying it out PSG now, or at least thinking a bit more about it.

Comment: "the simplest approach is to check what to do if the button is detected.. you can take action, or ignore it" - this works thank you

Answer (score 0):

This was an [issue 2548](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/2548) in PySimpleGUI.

Since version 4.16.0 there is also a shortcut to **unbind a key** from an element:

> I've also added an `Element.unbind` method to match the `Element.bind` method. This will allow you to unbind *tkinter* events from an element without needing to access the element's Widget member variable.

Thus you can use following to unbind *tkinter*'s return key-press events (`'<Return>'`) from your element, which is not the button (with key `b1`) but the input (text-field with key `-INPUT-`):

```py
# window['b1'].update(bind_return_key=False)  # raises error
window['-INPUT-'].unbind('<Return>')
```

Analogously you can bind the return-key to the text input by:

```py
# window['b1'].update(bind_return_key=True)  # raises your error
window['-INPUT-'].bind('<Return>', None) # bind just the return key with no modifiers
```

See also PySimpleGUI's call-reference:

- [`bind`](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#bind)
- [`unbind`](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/call%20reference/#unbind)

Comment: @MikefromPSG I learned a lot, thanks! BTW: never used PSG before, now I tested, found & fixed the issue ... next I will read your answer and learn again.